# Does stuff become countable when enumerated?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

Consider a conversation with a sentence:

S: "I bought milk and honey."

What is a grammatically correct question referring to the sentence S?

Q1: "Where did you put it?" or

Q2: "Where did you put them?"

Comment: Even though *milk* and *honey* are not countable, there are two items so together they are plural. For example, *"Fear, surprise, and ruthless efficiency **are** our three chief weapons."* But that doesn't make them countable.

Comment: In other words, the *set* is quantifiable, but any individual item *from* the set is not quantifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with TRomano's answer, I would go for

> Where did you put it?

Thinking about why I still see the two mass nouns together as a mass noun and not as countable, I wondered about buying beer and (white) wine.

> I bought beer and wine.
>   I put half of **it** in the fridge, the other half in the cellar for later.

Half of **them** would seemingly split my stuff into two parts, maybe one part being the beer, one part being the wine, anyway, not clear.

If I buy *bottles* of beer and *bottles* of wine, obviously,

> I put half of **them** in the fridge.

But of course, then I bought countable items to start with. If I bought beer and six bottles of wine, I'm afraid I'd have to specify separately what I did with both beverages.

Interestingly, I *would* refer to *milk and honey* (or wine and beer) as countable when referring to them in a different way:

> Beer and wine are two of my favourite drinks.

But then, I am referring to both of them as *a kind of* drink. Even only mentioning beer, I would treat it as "countable" when referring to it then:

> Beer is **one** of my favourite drinks.

The difference is that in the original sentence, I am not referring to the two things as *types of stuff*, but to uncountable amounts of them.

For those being thrown off by the beer and wine because they are more similar than milk and honey, the beer and wine example, and putting it in the fridge works the same way for:

> I bought flour and rice.
>   I put half of **it** in jars in the kitchen.

Or *honey and rice*. Or I bought milk and honey for use in my automatic hot drinks dispenser: I put half of **it** in the machine.

Comment: That's a quick downvote :) Coming from someone who cares to explain what "I put half of them in the fridge" means to them?

Comment: your example has little to do with the question. "beer and wine" is *very* different from "milk and honey". "beer and wine" refers to a collection of two similar drinks that people frequently group together. saying "i put half of the beer and wine in the fridge" does indeed make sense. but saying "i put half the milk and honey in the fridge does not". milk and honey are two VERY different things. you would need to say "i put half of the milk and half of the honey in the fridge". "where did you put them?" as an answer to OP's question is just wrong, or at least VERY strange sounding.

Comment: ran out of room but wanted to add "i put half of the beer and wine in the fridge" only makes sense because you're really putting half the *bottles* in the fridge. you're not literally pouring half of the liquid beer and half of the liquid wine into the fridge.

Comment: Very interesting. Milk and honey are two items that I consider liquid and that I would store in a fridge. I'd be very interested if you could elaborate in an answer how the similarity of the the products influences their countability. What about if I bought flour and rice and put half of **it** in the cellar? Or, in _jars in the kitchen_? And what If I put _milk and honey_ in vats in my larder? Could I not put half of **it** there? I dare say that flour and rice are at least as different as milk and honey.

Comment: "i bought flour and rice and put half of it in the cellar" does not make sense to me. half of what? the flour and rice combined by weight? half of each item? "half of them" doesn't make sense either. they're two *different* things. you're making this very confusing by talking about "half" of the item(s). OP simply asked whether the singular or plural should be used when talking about two items. clearly it's the plural, as you are dealing with two separate items: honey and milk.

Comment: It's the container, not the substance. If you buy shoe polish and honey, things totally unrelated (except to Curly Howard), you cannot put half in the cupboard and half in the basement, and not because one's polish and the other's food, but because they don't typically sell them retail by the six-pack or the case.

Comment: yes thank you @TRomano, that's a better explanation. i don't understand why the comparison to beer and wine was brought up in the first place. it's not relevant at all.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but I upvoted, because "Where did you put it" is a viable form, but it has nothing to do with the countability of the nouns in question.  One is referring there to the bag of groceries.

Comment: @sgroves: the comparison came up because milk and honey is confusing, as it has become a standard expression. If I buy shoe polish and bread, and I put half of it in the cellar, I put half the shoe polish in the cellar and I put half the bread in the cellar. I introduced the half to confirm my idea I would use _it_ in more situations than just _where did I put it?_ I do not see where the _difference_ between the items comes into play, but I look forward to your answer. It certainly _is_ relevant to this question.

Comment: "If I buy shoe polish and bread, and I put half of it in the cellar, I put half the shoe polish in the cellar and I put half the bread in the cellar." i disagree - the sentence as worded is not clear at all to me. you could certainly say it and someone *might* understand what you mean, but if an english speaker did what you described, they would say "i put half of each in the cellar", or something like that. "it" simply cannot refer to "the shoe polish and bread" (at least not without more context, such as them being referred to collectively as "groceries").

Comment: Although this answer by the number of the votes does not seem to be canonically accepted, I accepted it because together with its comments it analyses the boundary between a concept being countable and uncountable. In my question I put examples of milk and honey, but one always wishes to know how to treat a general example.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you put them?  Them = those items.

Comment: But you could certainly ask *Where did you put it all?* which makes the question more interesting.

Comment: Using "it all" for two items, I think not, but for several items, sure. But it would mean "Where did you find room to store all of those items? The cupboards were jam-packed."

Comment: Not sure you have my point. "It all" and "them all" are both possible, but they do not have the same meaning. The milk is filling up the refrigerator and the honey is overflowing the jars (and the eggs *are* in danger of rolling off the shelf); where shall we put it all?

Comment: That was exactly the point I got.

Answer (score 0):

Either.

Where did you put them... the items you bought?

Where did you put it... that which you bought?